# LibGDX - Creating an infinitely looping animation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to create an infinitely looping animation in libgdx. The problem is when I run it, the animation will run the first cycle, but then crash because of a NullPointerException.

I have set the animation playMode to loop, by setting the boolean looping to true when calling getKeyFrame():

```
currentFrame = globeAnimation.getKeyFrame(time, true);
```

When I run this, it will work for keyframes 1-40 (the number of frames in my animation, but then will crash with this error the second it reaches keyframe 41 with this error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I also tried setting the playMode to loop by setting it in the constructor:

```
globeAnimation = new Animation(GLOBE_ANIMATION_FRAME_RATE, globeAnimationTextureRegions, PlayMode.LOOP);
```

For some reason when I do this, it gives me an error stating that it

```
cannot resovle constructor for 
Animation(float,TextureRegion[],PlayMode) constructor Animation.Animation(float,Array<? extends TextureRegion>,PlayMode)
```

This doesn't make sense to me, because the framework has a constructor that takes those exact parameters.

```
public Animation (float frameDuration, Array<? extends TextureRegion> keyFrames, PlayMode playMode) {

    this.frameDuration = frameDuration;
    this.animationDuration = keyFrames.size * frameDuration;
    this.keyFrames = new TextureRegion[keyFrames.size];
    for (int i = 0, n = keyFrames.size; i < n; i++) {
        this.keyFrames[i] = keyFrames.get(i);
    }

    this.playMode = playMode;
}
```

Can some one please explain either why that constructor isn't working or an alternative route to making this work.

**Edit:**

Phil Anderson found out why the constructor wasn't resolving: I had to replace globeAnimationTextureRegions with

```
new Array<TextureRegion>(globeAnimationTextureRegions).
```

for the constructor to resolve.

Comment: Make sure you imported the right type of Animation (check package name).

Comment: @Tenfour04 I imported com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error...

```
cannot resovle constructor for 
Animation(float,TextureRegion[],PlayMode) constructor Animation.Animation(float,Array<? extends TextureRegion>,PlayMode)
```

Becuase you're passing in a Java array of TextureRegions, and the parameter type is a libGdx Array object of generic type TextureRegion.

Try something like...

```
globeAnimation = new Animation(GLOBE_ANIMATION_FRAME_RATE, new Array<TextureRegion>(globeAnimationTextureRegions), PlayMode.LOOP);
```

Comment: Your idea fixed the constructor not resolving, and allowed PlayMode to be set to LOOP, but for some reason it is still giving me a NullPointerException, after running through the first cycle of the animation. It seems like PlayMode.LOOP is not actually functioning like its supposed to. Do you think there is something wrong with the framework, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually nvm, your answer did fix it, there was just one small mistype that was screwing things up. Thank you!